# What is the correct syntax Syntax for WHERE keyword in VBA Code

Tags: sql, vba, database, string, character-encoding

I'm building a string that is going to be a sql execution in my access db. for proper source citing, I'm using a guide by [Allen Brown Audit](http://allenbrowne.com/AppAudit.html) as a template to save changes to my main db.

here is the code that is currently giving me trouble:

```
' If this was not a new record, save the old values.
If Not bWasNewRecord Then
    sSQL = "INSERT INTO " & sAudTmpTable & " ( audType, audDate, audUser, ID, Campus, Building, Room, `Device Type`, Model, Domain, `Serial Tag`, Barcode, HostName, `Custodian Name`, Notes ) " & _
        "SELECT 'EditFrom' AS Expr1, Now() AS Expr2, NetworkUserName() AS Expr3, " & sTable & "ID, Campus, Building, Room, `Device Type`, Model, Domain, `Serial Tag`, Barcode, Hostname, `Custodian Name`, Notes " & _
        "FROM " & sTable & " WHERE " & sTable & "." & sKeyField & " = " & lngKeyValue & ";"
    db.Execute sSQL, dbFailOnError
End If
```

currently it's returning an error of "Too few parameters. Expected 1.", which makes me think it is the WHERE clause and the string concatenation after that's causing it. My main question is whether this problem is a syntax problem, where I just needed to escape or add a double-quote somewhere, or a logic problem with the statement, and what I'm trying to do: which is select a record from a criteria, where the ID of the changed record matches an ID in the DB?
any notes or comments are welcome, and thank you for your time.

Comment: What does `Debug.Print sSQL` leave in your debug window? Is it what you expect?

Comment: I put one before and after the ssql string, and got this:
DELETE FROM tempInventoryAuditTable;
INSERT INTO tempInventoryAuditTable ( audType, audDate, audUser, ID, Campus, Building, Room, `Device Type`, Model, Domain, `Serial Tag`, Barcode, HostName, `Custodian Name`, Notes ) SELECT 'EditFrom' AS Expr1, Now() AS Expr2, NetworkUserName() AS Expr3, InventoryID, Campus, Building, Room, `Device Type`, Model, Domain, `Serial Tag`, Barcode, Hostname, `Custodian Name`, Notes FROM Inventory WHERE Inventory.ID = 384;

which is what I'm expecting, as the ID matches the record I'm editing

Comment: would it be better formatting to remove the spaces from those fields, and adjust the db field properties accordingly?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Which line causes the "Too few parameters" error?

Comment: I believe it's specifically the line:
"FROM " & sTable & " WHERE " & sTable & "." & sKeyField & " = " & lngKeyValue & ";"

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SQL Server, you'll want something like

```
SELECT Room
, [Device Type]
, Model
, Domain
, [Serial Tag]
```

For other RDBMSs (maybe for JetDB = Access), you'll want quotes instead of square brackets.  (Quotes may actually work for SQL Server as well, I just usually use square brackets.)

```
SELECT Room
, "Device Type"
, Model
, Domain
, "Serial Tag"
```

...and for RDBMSs who are case sensitive (like Oracle), quote everything (which doesn't hurt anyway)...

```
SELECT "Room"
, "Device Type"
, "Model"
, "Domain"
, "Serial Tag"
```